# Cygwin make error

Tags: makefile, cygwin

**I was compiling a source code, and it always fails at make command, below is the error message.**

```
gcc: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: \
  warning: --export-dynamic is not supported for PE targets,         \
  did you mean --export-all-symbols?
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: \
  warning: --export-dynamic is not supported for PE targets,         \
  did you mean --export-all-symbols?
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/alimjan/slim502/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/alimjan/slim502/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alimjan/slim502/src'
Making all in lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/alimjan/slim502/lib'
Cannot execute /bin/lmntal
Makefile:422: recipe for target `config.il' failed
make[1]: *** [config.il] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alimjan/slim502/lib'

Makefile:293: recipe for target `all-recursive' failed

make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

(Above lines broken to display)

I could not solve this. I am new to `make` and don't know what to do?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is when none of the source code is shown here.

Comment: source code is too big. do you think problem is come from source code or from cygwin or windows related ? I compiled it cygwin directory on windows 7.

Comment: For instance, parts of the Makefile around `line 422` would be useful and possibly any relevant `make` variables. See: [gcc linker docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).  Probably you can remove the `-rdynamic`, was the code for Linux originally?

Comment: yes, the code is c make project dveloped on ubuntu .

Comment: 422 lines? And it delegates to at least three layers of recursion in the same directory? This makefile was automatically generated, or incompetently written, or both. You appear to have inherited a [Big Ball of Mud](http://www.laputan.org/mud/) and you have my sympathy; debugging it might turn out to be trivial, or a huge task, there's no way to tell without wading into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when a makefile output looks as severe as your output, then it is because of the environment of which it is being used on has changed -- it could perhaps be that some external files have been moved or deleted or it could be that the make is too big, especially if the make is recursive in nature ( stay away from recursive makefiles; go NR)

Anyway if I where you I would look into where the environment had changed -- perhaps if your project is in a version system - try a different branch

Trying to solve the problems in the makefile could be very difficult and so it is better to go back to a version that worked and then move on from there

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure this is a problem with the makefile.  The error is:

```
Cannot execute /bin/lmntal
```

I'm fairly sure if you tried to run "/bin/lmntal" yourself from the command line you'd get a similar error.  It seems that your build requires some extra utility in order to run, that you don't have or which isn't working on your system.  Does that file (`/bin/lmntal`) exist?  Is it executable?  Is it a script and if so, does the first line refer to an interpreter that exists and is executable?  Is it a 32bit program (use `file /bin/lmntal`) while you're using a 64bit operating system and if so, do you have the 32bit versions of libc, etc. installed on your Ubuntu system?  Or vice versa (if you have a 32bit Ubuntu and the utility is a 64bit program you won't be able to run it at all)?

Alternatively it could be that this program is supposed to be found somewhere else or named something else, and your makefile *is* at fault because some variables are not set; for example the makefile could say something like `$(FOODIR)/bin/lmntal` and for some reason the variable `$(FOODIR)` is not set.

If you provide the details above (file exists?  Permissions?  `file` output?  Complete rule at line 422 of the makefile?) we can provide more help.